# How to make inside function not go out of main function scope when doing chaining?

Tags: javascript, scope, chaining

Example:

```
function testFunc() {
  this.insideFunc = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
  return this;
}

testFunc().insideFunc("Hi!");
insideFunc("Hi again!");
```

Why the inside function is visible in global scope, how to prevent that ?

Comment: try `var tst = new testFunc(); tst.insideFunc("hey"); insideFunc ("Hey2");`

Comment: Is `this` in the function not in the same object as the function itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on ethagnawl's answer, you can use this trick to force your function to `new` itself if the caller forgets:

```
function testFunc() {
    // if the caller forgot their new keyword, do it for them
    if (!(this instanceof testFunc)) {
        return new testFunc();
    }

    this.insideFunc = function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    return this;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qd7cW/

Answer (score 5):

That's because `this` is `window`.

To use `this` in this manner, you'd have to use:

```
var _testFunc = new testFunc();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```js
var testFunc = function() {
    function insideFunc(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
    return {
        insideFunc: insideFunc
    }
}
testFunc().insideFunc("Hi!");
insideFunc("Hi again!");
```